# How can write "Chapter" in upper case and center of the page in report class?

Tags: chapters, titles, titlesec

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan,}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.0in, left=1in, right=1.in,  
            footskip=2.0cm, % footskip margin
           ]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{Introduction}
The requirement of wireless communications systems urge designers to continual development in wireless transceiver RFICs design. Application of wireless communication is developing dramatically. Different wireless protocols include the basis of GSM the CDMA protocol, the UMTS network the Global Positioning System wireless local area network (IEEE 802.11a/b/g), Bluetooth connectivity, the ZigBee Wifi and the WiMax network are operating in various frequencies and having distinct modulation techniques. According to wireless communication users want next smart phone shall support all wireless protocols with minimal power consumption, lower expenses and smaller size. Currently phones feature independent RF frontend \& digital basebandband processors for each wireless protocol that not only need greater chip space but also waste more power. In order to decrease power dissipation, complicated interface, cost and space need of smart phone, future mobile receiver should have one wideband high-performance RF frontend to handle all communication via wireless protocols. The LNA designing is most crucial work in RF front end and can greatly affect the overall efficiency of RF receiver.
\end{document}
```

[image: I want to insert chapter title as in this image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your formatting objective is to center-set the chapter header and get it typeset in **bold**, and if you don't want to change any other aspects of the header (such as the font and font size), I suggest you load the `sectsty` package and issue the commands

```
\usepackage{sectsty}  % for \chapterfont macro
\chapterfont{\centering\MakeUppercase}
```

in the preamble. Actually, all-uppercase words, especially if they're typeset at a large font size, benefit greatly from being letterspaced. I therefore suggest you change the two commands above to

```
\usepackage{sectsty}     % for \chapterfont macro
\usepackage{letterspace} % for \lsstyle macro
\chapterfont{\lsstyle\centering\MakeUppercase}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{%amsfonts, % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
            amsmath,
            amssymb,
            amsthm,
            etoolbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{sectsty}     % for \chapterfont macro
\usepackage{letterspace} % for \lsstyle macro
\chapterfont{\lsstyle%   <-- optional
             \centering\MakeUppercase}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\usepackage{xurl}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, 
            filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. Is it possible to change the font size of "Chapert" and its title?

Comment: @SamiaRani - Sure. Just change `\chapterfont{\lsstyle\centering\MakeUppercase}` to, say, `\chapterfont{\LARGE\lsstyle\centering\MakeUppercase}`.